# enabled windows authentication on my web site

Tags: iis

I deployed one of my web site on our server and enabled windows authentication. I tried DNS flush and restarted the application pool and my web site. when I open the web site on my browser, I keep getting this message:

[image]

this message is only coming for https and not http.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This requires thorough analysis of your site/app settings on IIS, so a forum like this won't help. Please open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com or hire a consultant.

Comment: could you please share your web.config file?